# I don't understand this SQL behavior for select

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

Given two tables :

A with row : [1641, 1468] Amongst others
B with row : [1641, 1468] Amongst others

If I run this :

```
select distinct A.c1, B.c2
from A, B
where A.c1 <> B.c1 and A.c2 <> B.c2
```

I was expecting not to get that tuple back. Although when running the command it returns that tuple.

Is there an explanation for this behavior ? Using SQLite.

Comment: You really should write proper `JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit `A, B` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
A
---
C1 C1
-----
1  2
1  3
```

.

```
B
---
C1 C1
-----
1  2
1  3
```

The join will first produce

```
A.C1 A.C2 B.C1 B.C2
-------------------
1    2    1    3
1    3    1    2
```

With distinct and just the selected columns it will be

```
A.C1 B.C2
---------
1    3
1    2
```

I suspect you want something like

```
select distinct A.c1, B.c2
from A, B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2)
```

Comment: Do two inserts. `INSERT INTO "a" VALUES(1641,0);` and `INSERT INTO "b" VALUES(0,1468);`. Your query will still return {1641,1468}.

Answer (score 2):

Can't replicate that.

```
$ sqlite3 t.db
SQLite version 3.7.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> create table a (c1 integer, c2 integer);
sqlite> create table b (c1 integer, c2 integer);
sqlite> insert into a values (1641, 1468);
sqlite> insert into b values (1641, 1468);
sqlite> select * from a;
1641|1468
sqlite> select * from b;
1641|1468
sqlite> select distinct A.c1, B.c2
   ...> from A, B
   ...> where A.c1 <> B.c1 and A.c2 <> B.c2;
sqlite>
```

After comments . . .

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE a (
c1 integer,
c2 integer);
INSERT INTO "a" VALUES(1641,1468);
INSERT INTO "a" VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO "a" VALUES(3,4);
CREATE TABLE b (
c1 integer, c2 integer
);
INSERT INTO "b" VALUES(1641,1468);
INSERT INTO "b" VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO "b" VALUES(5,6);
COMMIT;
sqlite> select distinct A.c1, B.c2
   ...> from A, B
   ...> where A.c1 <> B.c1 and A.c2 <> B.c2;
1|6
1|1468
3|2
3|6
3|1468
1641|2
1641|6
```

Still don't get the tuple {1641, 1468}.

If you just want the rows that aren't duplicated you might try something more along these lines.

```
sqlite> select a.c1, a.c2 from a
   ...> left join b on (b.c1 = a.c1 and b.c2 = a.c2)
   ...> where b.c1 is null and b.c2 is null
   ...> union all
   ...> select b.c1, b.c2 from b
   ...> left join a on (b.c1 = a.c1 and b.c2 = a.c2)
   ...> where a.c1 is null and a.c2 is null;
3|4
1641|73
5|6
```

Comment: If you add another row to either a or b that isn't that tuple, you will be able to replicate it.

Comment: With further testing that is exactly it. How would I make it so if one tuple does not satisfy the where clause, regardless of other rows it's not selected.

Comment: @Catcall You're right, I believe if you add these two rows you should be able to reproduce it: insert into "A"  values(1641, 0);
insert into "B"  values(0, 1468);

Comment: @mangoDrunk: Yes, that returns the tuple {1641,1468} using the OP's query. But using the query I posted at the bottom of my answer--which is, I admit, guesswork about what the OP might be wanting to do--you won't see that tuple.

Comment: @Catcall Nice, I'm surprised the OP chose another answer as yours does at least provide that requirement, whereas the other doesn't.

Comment: @mangoDrunk: You're right. With the data you and I used, the accepted answer will still produce the tuple {1641,1468}.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, your join is producing a Cartesian product.

```
create table A(c1 int, c2 int);
create table B(c1 int, c2 int);
insert into A(c1, c2) values(1641, 1468), (1, 5);
insert into B(c1, c2) values(1641, 1468), (1, 5);
select * from A, B;
```

Which will result in:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| A.c1 | A.c2 | B.c1 | B.c2 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1641 | 1468 | 1641 | 1468 |
|    1 |    5 | 1641 | 1468 |
| 1641 | 1468 |    1 |    5 |
|    1 |    5 |    1 |    5 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

So, when running your query, the where clause will restrict the first row and the last row. Which will leave us with:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| A.c1 | A.c2 | B.c1 | B.c2 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    5 | 1641 | 1468 |
| 1641 | 1468 |    1 |    5 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

And running your full query, will result in:

```
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 | 1468 |
| 1641 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

But, we can construct some rows so that we will get it regardless since you're using `A.c1` and `B.c2`:

```
insert into A(c1, c2) values(1641, 5);
insert into B(c1, c2) values(1, 1468);
```

Which will result in a row with [1641, 1468].

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I ran the following test on ms sql server 05:

```
create table a  
(  
c1 int,  
c2 int  
)  
create table b  
(  
c1 int,  
c2 int  
)   

insert into a values(1641,1468)
insert into a values(1641,1111)
insert into b values(1641,1468)
insert into b values(1112,1345)

select distinct A.c1, B.c2
   from A, B
where A.c1 <> B.c1 and A.c2 <> B.c2;
```

my results were:

```
c1   |   c2
-------------
1641 |   1345
```

As you can see, I did not get that original tuple back which is what Kassym was expecting.

I guess sqllite is different, but I would have expected it to work the way Kassym expected as well.

-m

Comment: I see- I mean, yes, you get that tuple back. But you **should** get that tuple back in that case. a1.c1 <> b1.c1 and a2.c2 <> b2.c2 - totally correct, no? :)